# JPA No transaction Active

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

I am using the JPA Framework to achieve Database Persistence of information.

This is how I used I created a class like this:

```
public class ManageConnection {

 private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
 private static EntityManager em = null;
 private static String persitenceName="locationtracker";

 public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if(emf==null || !emf.isOpen())
        emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persitenceName);
    if(em==null || !em.isOpen())
        em=emf.createEntityManager();

    return em;
 }
 public static void closeEntityManager(){
    if(em!=null && em.isOpen())
        em.close()
 }
}
```

Then in my servlet  I am using like this:

```
public void doPost(blablah){   
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    for(blah blah){

         Manageconnection.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            <PersistenceObject> objName = new <PersistenceObject>();
                 //properties of the objName to persist
         ManageConnection.getEntityManager().persist(<objName>);
         Manageconnection.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    Manageconnection.closeEntityManager();
}
```

Now my problem is I get **Transaction is already active** Exception whenever I passes the values to my Servlet also the same code works  perfect when there is no Servlet thing, I mean using main method in a Test class it is running like charm, but it throws exception when  runs in Servlet.

Please help me..............
;(
Thanks in advance,
Ankur

Comment: and if your transaction ever fails then your logic falls apart since the txn will still be active

Answer (score 1):

All of your `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManagerFactory` is used `static`. It is the class level and for all instance of `ManageConnection`. At first, if an instance of `ManageConnection` is created, it will be share other instance of `ManageConnection`. My suggestion is just try without using `static`.

Comment: so should i use the new instance of class for creating entitymanager.

Comment: @ankur verma, You should use new instance of `EntityManager`. If you like to control the `Transaction` among multiple process, you have to share this `EntityManager` instance to the processes you would like to control.

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume you don't want to use EJBs, but instead want to use POJOs.
   (Note there's a simple solution where Session Beans carry out JPA operations and  Servlets call EJBs - less code, less ugly, does what you want.)
2. Each servlet session should have its own entity manager instance. Remove every case of "static" from the class ManageConnection. Then in your servlet, when you create the HttpSession, additionally create an instance of ManageConnection and store it as an attribute in the session.

   public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

   ```
   private ManageConnections getManageConnections(HttpSession sess) {
       ManageConnection manageConnection = 
           (ManageConnection)sess.getAttribute("userManageConnection");
       if (manageConnection == null) {
           ManageConnection manageConnection = new ManageConnection();
           sess.setAttribute("userManageConnection", manageConnection);
       }
   }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      this.processRequest(req, resp);
   }

   public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
       HttpSession sess = req.getSession(true);
       ManageConnections manageConnections = this.getManageConnections(sess);
       // remaining JPA operations
   }
   ```

   }
3. Get the EntityManager:

   ```
   // inside processRequest() above
   EntityManager em = manageConnection.getEntityManager();
   ```
4. Start Tx, do entity operations, End Tx

   ```
   // inside processRequest() above
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    <PersistenceObject> objName = new <PersistenceObject>();
    //properties of the objName to persist
    em.persist(<objName>);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
   ```
5. Close the EntityManager before the user finishes their session.  This is important, because without it some implementations will need to be restarted very often - especially during development when you're rebuilding and redeploying often (I'm looking at you, EclipseLink on Glassfish, deployed using netbeans modules).

   ```
    make servlet:  extends HttpSessionListener

    // add the following methods, so we get a callback to sessionDestroyed when the 
    // session is closed via user logout (terminateSession) or session timeout:

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
       config.getServletContext().addListenter(this.class.getName());
    }


    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
          ManageConnections manageConnections = this.getManageConnections();
          manageConnections.getEntityManager().close();
          manageConnections.getEntityManagerFactor().close();
    }
   ```

As I said - a bit ugly, because we are using a very stateful Application Managed Entity Manager in a stateless Servlet.  Much cleaner to use a Transaction Scoped Entity Manager in a Stateless Session Bean or Extended Scope (or Application Managed) Entity Manager in a Stateful Session Bean... quite a JPA mouthful, but easier than it sounds.
:-)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I solved the problem like this.please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

**I created two classes like this:**

```
 //This class has the EntityManagerFactory instance that is going to be shared between the classes
 public class ManageConnection {

  protected static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
  private static String persitenceName="locationtracker";

  //Anonymous Block that is going to be called (beofre) on every call for constructor of this class
  //whether through inheritance or normal instantiation
  {
    if(emf==null || !emf.isOpen())
        emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persitenceName);
  }


  public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
    return ManageConnection.emf;
  }
}
//This class actually handles the trasactional management
 public class ManageTransaction extends ManageConnection{

   /**
    * 
    */
   public ManageTransaction() {
    super();
    this.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    this.transaction = this.entityManager.getTransaction();

   }

   /**
    * @param entityManager
    * @param transaction
    */
   public ManageTransaction(EntityManager entityManager,EntityTransaction transaction) {
    super();
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.transaction = transaction;
   }

   private EntityManager entityManager;
   private EntityTransaction transaction;

   /**
    * @return the entityManager
    */
   public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
   }

   /**
    * @param entityManager the entityManager to set
    */
   public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
   }

   /**
    * @return the transaction
    */
   public EntityTransaction getTransaction() {
    return transaction;
   }

   /**
    * @param transaction the transaction to set
    */
   public void setTransaction(EntityTransaction transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
   }

   public void closeEntityManager(){
    if(entityManager!=null && entityManager.isOpen()){
        entityManager.close();
    }
   }

   public void close(){
    this.closeEntityManager();
   }

   public void flush(){
    entityManager.flush();
   }

   public void begin(){
    this.transaction.begin();
   }

   public void commit(){
    this.flush();
    this.transaction.commit();
   }

   public void persist(Object objToPersist){
    this.entityManager.persist(objToPersist);
   }
 }//end of ManageTransaction class
```

Now if I want to use this, I use like this:

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
ManageTransaction mt = new ManageTransaction();
```

### Scenario 1

```
 mt.getEntityManager().find(blah,blah);//works perfectly
```

### Scenario 2

```
mt.begin();
<PersistenceObject> objName = new <PersistenceObject>();
mt.persist(objName);
mt.close();
```

### Scenario 3

```
String jpaquery = "blah blah";
TypedQuery<ClassType> tq = mt.getEntityManager().createQuery(jpaquery,<Class>.class);
List<ClassType> all = tq.getResultList();
```

In this way every time creating new Transaction is not required I just create a single transaction and use that transaction every where in my class and at the end closes it.

That way my problem of sharing **EntityManager** is solved and thus never throws the **Exception** at any case.

:)